# Should programs be compiled with a prefix?

Tags: linux

When compiling programs, should they be given their own `--prefix` (eg /usr/local/php5/) to keep all the files for that program separate, or just installed in the default location (eg `/usr/local/`)

It seems to me that installing with a prefix is better, since it makes uninstalling easy. If this is the case, why do programs not default to a custom install location?

**What are the pros and cons of a custom `--prefix`?**

Comment: According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) if you want each program to have its own directory, then you should use the `/opt` prefix, not `/usr`. Quoting from the documentation: *"A package to be installed in /opt must locate its static files in a separate /opt/<package> [...] Programs to be invoked by users must be located in the directory /opt/<package>/bin [...]. If the package includes UNIX manual pages, they must be located in /opt/<package>/share/man [...]."*.

Answer (score 3):

When you type "php" in the shell, the shell first looks up the PATH variable ("echo $PATH"), and goes dir-by-dir to find that "php" binary to run. paths like "/bin", "/usr/bin", etc. are there. Paths like "/usr/local/php5/bin" are not (unless you add them yourself).

In *nix, it is a standard to put binaries into "*/bin" folders, configs to "/etc", etc., and everybody expects them to be there (so if you have a script which calls php, you'll have a problem if it's not in a "standard" folder.

Uninstalling is never a problem if you use a package manager, since it keeps track of all files installed, and it can uninstall them. If you use a debian/slackware/redhat based distribution, check out "[checkinstall](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/)", which allows you to create packages from your compiled code, which you can then easily uninstall when needed